# Show Right Click Options on the Selected List View Record Only - Winforms C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

[alt text http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/9417/snapshotapp.jpg](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/9417/snapshotapp.jpg)

The ContextMenuStrip tied to the ListView control. However, the right click option (edit)
appear where ever i click on the ListView area, this gives me exceptional error because the implementation of edit can only cope with a selected row. I only want it to appear when on a selected row (blue highlighted row). How can i do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reset the ContextMenuStrip property back to (none).  Implement the MouseUp event handler and use ListView.HitTest() to find out where it was clicked.  For example:

```
    private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
            var loc = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
            if (loc.Item != null) contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView1, e.Location);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to let you know, it didn't work, when i right click i don't get the right click option (edit). I wonder why. I'm trying to figure it out, once i get it will let you know. Any more suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Hmm, there's no failure mode there, other than not setting the MouseUp event properly.  Use the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.

Comment: Worked! It was my mistake, i choose MouseUp on the wrong control...Thanks!

Comment: I have the listview inside a panel and i added the contextmenustrip to it, and this doesn´t work at all...